bad certificate kubernetes master node
"tls: bad certificate"
""level":"warn","ts":"2024-06-02T11:14:58.713Z","caller":"embed/config_logging.go:169","msg":"rejected connection","remote-addr":"...:47558","server-name":"","error":"remote error: tls: bad certificate" "
When restarting one master node, this error appeared. However, after resuming a particular node after then the next master node, we did not find any solutions. but the point is the certificate was quite ok.

Can you please elaborate your issue for better resolution. Also check this Kubernetes official document for managing TLS certificate in a cluster.

This is not a certificate issue. The cluster has been running for almost four years and is extensive, with nearly 87 worker nodes and five master nodes. On Sunday, I needed to reboot master-1 for maintenance purposes, and I instantly got this error from master-2. If I reboot master-2, the error disappears, but the root cause of the issue remains unknown.
Please let me know if you need further assistance or have additional details to share!
Thanks @Srividya

Hi Bipul,
Could you please tell us if you are still facing this issue.
As per the above error message, this might have occurred because of a cluster with a faulty etcd certificate or an expired peer certificate, which is preventing upgrades in a production cluster, according to the shared error message.

Refer this document which is related to etcd certificates expiration and additionally go through this document and please let us know if it was helpful.
